# Package VS2008 install project in XP for Win7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, .net-3.5, windows-xp, setup-deployment

I'm developing on WinXP Pro 32bit using VS2008 Pro.  Do I need to create an installation/deployment project in any special way to get my application on install on a Win7 Pro 64Bit computer?

At the moment, the deployment setup project I have setup in my project only seems to install on WinXP and fails on Win7.

When setting up the installation project for WinXP, I set it up to automatically install .NET 3.5, Windows Report Writer, SQL Server Compact and Windows Installer automatically if not available on the computer.

Comment: The package should work on Windows 7 64-bit. What is the exact behavior you are encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`TargetPlatform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1behyzx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to `x64` in the deployment project properties.